# fastest way to get element values from an array object in php

Tags: php, arrays, object

I have something like this

```
Array
(
    [0] => stdClass Object
        (
            [CustomerID] => 14
            [Email] => joe.blogs@example.com
            [LastName] => Blogs
            [BirthDayOfMonth] => 29
            [Gender] => 
            [Occupation] => 
            [SendSpecialOffers] => 1
            [SendReminderNotes] => 1
        )

    [1] => stdClass Object
        (
            [CustomerID] => 1460
            [Email] => example@example.com
            [LastName] => Example
            [BirthDayOfMonth] => 5
            [Gender] => F
            [Occupation] => 
            [SendSpecialOffers] => 1
            [SendReminderNotes] => 1
        )
);
```

I would like get Email address of each separated by commas, something like this

```
'joe.blogs@example', 'example@example.com'
```

I know i could iterate it through foreach but i got a really big list, is there anyway to do it faster? thanks

**Now, how can i remove the indexes based some email addresses?**

Comment: I hope those email address owners don't mind you posting them here... ;)

Comment: "but i got a really big list" - the perils of ORM!

Answer (score 6):

You can do this with array map and a function but this will also iterate your array

```
echo implode(',',array_map('getEmail',$array));

function getEmail($obj)
{
  return $obj->Email;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

The simplest solution would indeed be a `foreach()` to iterate over all the items of your array ; adding, for each item, the email to a another resulting array.

Maybe you could replace the foreach by a call to [`array_walk()`](http://www.php.net/array_walk), but it probably wouldn't change much :

- You wouldn't loop in PHP, as `array_walk` is coded in C *(could be a bit faster than foreach -- not sure, though)*
- But a function would be called for each item, instead of just a couple of PHP instructions.

You'd have to benchmark, to see if there is a significant difference in your specific case -- but I personnaly would go for the foreach, without thinking much more.

Answer (score 0):

**[`array_filter`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-filter.php)** is best..see the examples on manual

Comment: `array_filter()` returns an array of elements, that are treated "valid" according a given callback. Can you explain, how do you want to use it to extract an object property from every array element?